# starting mongodb single server as replica set to enable oplog through supervisord

Tags: mongodb, replication, supervisord

I want to start a single mongod instance with command
`mongod --config config/mongod.conf`
Once above process starts running I also have to call
`mongodb/bin/mongo --eval rs.initiate()`
Now the issue is I am starting mongod through supervisord
I want to perform both of the above operation one after another.
supervisord takes just 1 command to start the process which is first command. I have no other place to run the rs.initiate().
If I put both the command in shell script even then the control will be stuck with the first command itself.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could combine the commands into a single command.  I.e.,

`mongod --config config/mongod.conf && sleep 5 && mongodb/bin/mongo --eval rs.initiate()`

The sleep command assumes 5 seconds is enough for the mongod to come up and be  available for an rs.initiate().  Given you are initiating a replica set I assume you have no data?  If so, startup should be relatively quickly.  Also if you are attempting to make a single node replica set you might want to consider...

```
rs.initiate (
    {
        _id: "somereplicasetname",
        version: 1,
        members:
        [
            { _id: 0, host: "somehostname:27017" }
        ]
    }
)
```

... so that you don't need to configure the initiated replicaset any further.  The _id value (currently showing as `somereplicasetname`) is expected to match the replica set name in the config file `mongod.conf` and the `somehostname` is expected to resolve to the current host.

By the way, I assume you recognize you only need to initialize a replica set once, not every time you start the mongod process..

Comment: 1. about adding && unfortunately supervisord does not recognize the '&&' param
2. for the sleep I have added a call to rs.status() to check if mongod is up and running and added a longer timeout
3. how does rs.initialize work? if I turn down the mongod process how is it preserving state so that I don't need to run rs.initiate() again?

Comment: @ShilpaGupta - MongoDB is a database.  State can be preserved on disk in a database.  Unless, that is, you want to run the database in memory only (you have not specified memory-only so I assume it can persist to disk).  So, with the assumption you can store data on disk, calling rs.initiate() will create metadata in the database and is saved.  If you restart the cluster it recalls the state.  My comment is about how to configure a replica set once you have initiated the cluster with a request to make it a replica set versus a stand alone - which is what the rs.initiate() does.

Comment: ... and also, a replica-set (also known as 'rs') is for high availability.  It also includes the replication framework which is the basis for some features like change streams.  So when you call rs.initiate() you are saying to the database you want it to be a highly available replica set instead of a stand-alone database system.